# How do I filter a view by the node taxonomy you're currently on?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I've built a content type and added taxonomy to it. The user can choose one of the 10 terms from that vocabulary when they are building the content. On the node I want to build a sidebar that lists all the other nodes from this content type but filtered to be only the same taxonomy choice. I assume this is done through views but I can't figure out how to build that contextual filter that looks at the current nodes taxonomy.

Comment: Your contextual filter is the current node id taken from the url. You add a relationship to the taxonomy terms, then add a second relationship (in reverse I think) to nodes that contain the taxonomy terms and exclude the current node. Your fields must then be linked to the second relationship. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize what J. Reynolds said above.

Add Contextual Filter - Content: Has taxonomy term ID with following settings

[image]

then add contextual filter - Content:Nid (provide default value -> Content ID from URL) and in "More" section of that filter check "Exclude" checkbox, which will remove the currently viewed node from the list of nodes related by taxonomy term.